# Promisify all submethods on a node module

Tags: node.js, bluebird

I'm trying to Promisify the stripe module but running into an issue.

If I run:

```
const stripe = Promise.promisifyAll(require('stripe')(secretKey));
const response = await stripe.accounts.retrieveAsync();
```

retrieveAsync isn't a function. I have to do something like this:

```
const accounts = Promise.promisifyAll(stripe.accounts);
const response = await accounts.retrieveAsync();
```

But obviously this doesn't scale well. How can I promisify all of the submethods of this module? Thanks

Comment: `accounts` isn't defined in your first snippet. Did you mean `stripe.accounts`?

Comment: Yup, good eye, fixed

Comment: You could create your own recursive solution that would start with the stripe object, call `Promise.promisifyAll()` on it, then find any properties that also contain plain objects and call `Promise.promisifyAll()` on those child objects and repeat recursively.  For edge cases, you'd probably have to protect yourself from circular references by keeping a `Set` object of all objects you've already recursed and refusing to do one that you've already done.  There may be certain properties that you need to avoid processing (like `.prototype`).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
let stripe = require('stripe')(secretKey);
Promise.promisifyAll(Object.getPrototypeOf(stripe));
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a shot to it :

```
const stripe = Promise.promisifyAll(require('stripe')(secretKey));
const response = yield stripe.accounts.retrieve().promise();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that stripe v4.25 supports Promises, if you omit the callback.

With callback:

```
var stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_XXX')
stripe.plans.retrieve('number_one_month', (err, res) => console.log(res))
{ id: 'number_one_month', 
...
```

And with `then()`:

```
stripe.plans.retrieve('number_one_month').then(console.log)
{ id: 'number_one_month',
...
```

But I didn't find it in the documentation.